# Пройти авторизацию oauth.vk.com

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно пройти oauth.vk.com

`oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2890984&scope=notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,notifications,stats,ads,offline&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token`

допустим из консольного приложения,где есть некий метод `public String login(String email,String pass);` который возвращает **acces token**.

Как можно реализовать такое на Java?

Comment: Какие еще email и pass? Это API принимает client_id, а не логин и пароль от аккаунта Во-вторых - либо через VK SDK (но он вообще-то для Android, и для консольного придется основательно его исследовать), либо через браузерный движок. HTTP-запросы не рекомендуются - нет гарантии, что в один прекрасный день работать не перестанет.

Comment: ведь можно как-то распарсить страницу авторизации ,но не совсем понятно что делать после этого?

Comment: Страница как видите принимает client_id и возвращает access_token, вот его и надо выпарсить и затем в запросы к API (например photos.get или как его) добавлять параметром. Но, еще раз повторяю, это должен быть не парсинг а браузер, может оно там даже через JS делается и тогда в html вообще нет этого, только браузер или жуткий костыль, который вы не осилите и подавно.

Comment: А если про ту страницу, где логин и пароль, то есть не через API - то это другое. Здесь надо сниффером уметь пользоваться, им и исследовать и авторизацию и конкретно то, что надо. ну, и об аяксе иметь представление и вообще в веб-разработке понимать